# Measurability of centered Hardy-Littlewood maximal function with doubling measure

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, d, \mu)$ be a metric space with *doubling* measure $\mu$ a.e. every open ball has finite and positive measure $\mu$ and there exists $C>0$ such that

$$\mu(B(x,2r)) \le C\mu(B(x,r))$$
for every $x \in X$ and $r > 0$.

Juha Heinonen in the *Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces* (Chapter 2) considers *Hardy-Littlewood centered maximal function* $Mf$ on $(X, d, \mu)$ defined as

$$Mf(x) = \sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{\mu(B(x, r))} \int_{B(x, r)} |f|\, d\mu,$$

where $f \in L^1_{loc}(X)$.

Author doesn't mention about measurability of that function. I did some research and found results only for $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure, we can find proof for example in the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392563/sufficient-conditions-for-the-hardy-littlewood-maximal-function-mf-being-con, but the proof uses the fact for Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ that if $\lambda(B(x, r)) < t$ then we can choose $s > r$ small enough to get $\lambda(B(x,s)) < t$. It seems that we can't repeat this reasoning for doubling measures because of possible atoms. Is there any elegant way out of this situation?

Also in the case of $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ one can prove that supremum in the definition of $Mf$ can be taken only over rational $r$ and thus measurability of $Mf$ is implied by measurability of function under supremum (which is easy to check). But again, we use the fact mentioned above, but maybe changing arbitrary $r$ to rational $r$ is the point.

(The book *Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces* is open access)

Comment: Even in the presence of atoms, the quantity $\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f|\ d\mu$ is still left-continuous in $r$ (by monotone or dominated convergence), so one can restrict the rations $r$ to be rational without changing the value of the maximal function.

Comment: Thanks! I've just completed the details and it works.